# multi-threaded gSOAP services

Tags: multithreading, gsoap

Is there a way for the stub/skeleton compiler to generate threaded services (i.e. by spawning a thread for each request or by thread pooling) or do I have to manually add soap_copy(), pthread_create() ...

I know that -- according to the FAQ and user guide 7.2.4 -- gSOAP is thread safe and does support multi-threaded services. However, using the soapcpp2 -i flag I end up with

```
int DummyService::run(int port)
{   
    if (soap_valid_socket(bind(NULL, port, 100)))
    {   
        for (;;)
        {   
            if (!soap_valid_socket(accept()))
                 return this->error;
            (void)serve();
            soap_destroy(this);
            soap_end(this);
        }
    }
    else
        return this->error;

    return SOAP_OK;
}
```

Any hint?

Answer (score 3):

This may not be a direct treatment of your specific request, but it is as close as I could find...  (clipped from [http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soapdoc2.html#sec:mt](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/%7Eengelen/soapdoc2.html#sec:mt) )

The following example illustrates the use of threads to improve the quality of service by handling new requests in separate threads:

```
#include "soapH.h"
#include < pthread.h >
#define BACKLOG (100) // Max. request backlog
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   struct soap soap;
   soap_init(&soap);
   if (argc < 2) // no args: assume this is a CGI application
   {
      soap_serve(&soap); // serve request, one thread, CGI style
      soap_destroy(&soap); // dealloc C++ data
      soap_end(&soap); // dealloc data and clean up
   }
   else 
   {
      soap.send_timeout = 60; // 60 seconds
      soap.recv_timeout = 60; // 60 seconds
      soap.accept_timeout = 3600; // server stops after 1 hour of inactivity
      soap.max_keep_alive = 100; // max keep-alive sequence
      void *process_request(void*);
      struct soap *tsoap;
      pthread_t tid;
      int port = atoi(argv[1]); // first command-line arg is port
      SOAP_SOCKET m, s;
      m = soap_bind(&soap, NULL, port, BACKLOG);
      if (!soap_valid_socket(m))
         exit(1);
      fprintf(stderr, "Socket connection successful %d\n", m);
      for (;;)
      {
         s = soap_accept(&soap);
         if (!soap_valid_socket(s))
         {
            if (soap.errnum)
            {
               soap_print_fault(&soap, stderr);
               exit(1);
            }
            fprintf(stderr, "server timed out\n");
            break;
         } 
         fprintf(stderr, "Thread %d accepts socket %d connection from IP %d.%d.%d.%d\n", i, s, (soap.ip >> 24)&0xFF, (soap.ip >> 16)&0xFF, (soap.ip >> 8)&0xFF, soap.ip&0xFF);
         tsoap = soap_copy(&soap); // make a safe copy
         if (!tsoap)
           break;
         pthread_create(&tid, NULL, (void*(*)(void*))process_request, (void*)tsoap);
      }
   }
   soap_done(&soap); // detach soap struct
   return 0;
}
void *process_request(void *soap)
{
   pthread_detach(pthread_self());
   soap_serve((struct soap*)soap);
   soap_destroy((struct soap*)soap); // dealloc C++ data
   soap_end((struct soap*)soap); // dealloc data and clean up
   soap_done((struct soap*)soap); // detach soap struct
   free(soap);
   return NULL;
}
```

Note: the code does not wait for threads to join the main thread upon program termination.

There is additional threading information in the same area of the document referenced in the link above.  It may at least provide a starting place in your search for a solution.